# How to download code from a particular branch in AzureDevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-repos, feature-branch

I need to download all the files from the feature branch in AzureDevOps release pipeline. I am using Azure repo. Is there any task in AzureDevOps classic editor for the same? How to implement this using Powershell?

Comment: Hi @NCN, I have updated my answer with more detailed information. Please check it and have a try with the suggestions. Any progress, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**

In your release pipeline,

- if a previous step in the same job will check out the source repository but not check out the **feature** branch, you can use the [**git checkout**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) command to check out the **feature** branch to the local repository on the agent machine, and this command also will switch the current branch to **feature** in the local repository.

```sh
git checkout -b feature --track origin/feature
```

- if no previous step to check out any source version from the repository, you can use the [**git clone**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) command to only check out the the **feature** branch to the local.

```sh
git clone <Repo_URL> -b feature
```

You can use either **`Bash`** or **`PowerShell`** to execute these commands in your pipeline.